# How to export the pending Checkins in excel from isual studio 2010 - vs extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, checkin, vs-extensibility

I want to make a vs extension that i can export the "Pending Chekins" from Visual Studio 2010 solution in a excel file, i need to use the name, the folder , the modified time and the change type. It is posible? Some body knows how to programm in vs extension and get this kind of information.
Im using Visual Studio 2010 C# and Ms Visual Soursafe v 8.0.50727.42

Sorry for my bad english :(

Greetings
Bruno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is basically go to this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.aspx

This shows you all the available services & interfaces on Shell.Interop namespace, which will allow you to do what you want.

I am not 100% sure if it's the correct way, but one way to do it is to query glyph for an item, which should indicate when item is checked out by an user:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssccmanager2.getsccglyph.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166345.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.vsstateicon.aspx